# scipy.optimize.fim Error: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimum, fminsearch

I know that there are plenty of posts similar to mine but I really don't manage to apply them to my situation so please I ask for your help. Basically, my code is the following:

```
def Black_min(f, k, ann, vol, ex, cp):
    d1=(math.log(f/k)+0.5*vol**2*ex)/math.sqrt(vol**2*ex)
    d2=(math.log(f/k)-0.5*vol**2*ex)/math.sqrt(vol**2*ex)
    Price=cp*(f*norm.cdf(cp*d1)-k*norm.cdf(cp*d2))*ann*20000
    return Price

banana = lambda x: (Price_Cube[0][4]-Black_min(F[0], K[0][4], Annuity[0], x, Expiry[0], CP[4]))**2
xopt, fopt = scipy.optimize.fmin(func=banana, x0=[Vol_Cube[0][0]],  disp=False)
```

Price_Cube, K are lists of lists with numbers inside, Annuity, Expiry and CP are simply lists. When I run the code, I obtain this.

```
    xopt, fopt = scipy.optimize.fmin(func=banana, x0=[Vol_Cube[0][0]],  disp=False)

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I'm aware that it is a silly mistake, but I really don't see it. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: what is Vol_Cube

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot. It is a list of lists with numbers inside like Price_Cube.

Comment: Note that is you have the argument *retall=True* it will still return the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you try to assign the return value of `fmin` to two variables, `xopt` and `fopt`, but by default `fmin` only returns `xopt`. You should try

```
xopt = scipy.optimize.fmin(func=banana, x0=[Vol_Cube[0][0]])
```

If you also want the function value at the minimum, you have to set `full_output` to `True`, and then you also get some more diagnostics:

```
xopt, fopt, iter, funccalls, warnflags = scipy.optimize.fmin(func=banana, x0=[Vol_Cube[0][0]], full_output=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, with your help I have solved the problem.